# Inject EJB 3.0 in WebLogic Server v10.3

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

I am having some issues trying to inject a stateless EJB into an Application Client Project. Both the App Client and the EJB are in the same EAR. Using JNDI, I am able to retrieve an instance of the EJB, but I'm not sure how should I do it with the @EJB annotation. I've tried using @EJB(name="something"), @EJB(mappedName="something"), but all I get is a null. Here is my code:

```
@Remote
public interface TimerEjbTestService {
    public void testMethod();
}

@Stateless(mappedName="TimerEjbTestService")
public class TimerEjbTestBean implements TimerEjbTestService{

    public void testMethod() {
        System.out.println("Inside EJB.");
    }
}
```

With JNDI I'm able to get the instance as follows:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
TimerEjbTestService timerEjbTestService = (TimerEjbTestService) ctx.lookup("TimerEjbTestService#myejb.timerejbtestservice.services.TimerEjbTestService");
```

Any ideas on how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
@EJB
private TimerEjbTestService myBean;
```

In this way, the container injects the bean.

Also, since it is in the same ear (thus ran by the same JVM) the annotation for the interface should be `@Local` not `@Remote`.

Comment: I've already tried this, but all I get is a null reference, both with Local and Remote annotations. I've also tried EJB(mappedName="TimerEjbTestService") with no success.

Comment: @carcaret Try it without parameter mappedName in the Stateless annotation; or with name instead of mappedName. From the specification, mappedName need not be handeled by the app server: "Application servers are not required to support any particular form or type of mapped name, nor the ability to use mapped names. The mapped name is product-dependent and often installation-dependent." - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Stateless.html